# need help reseting a class instance

Tags: python

I'm trying to have my use(self) method change my self.text into an empty str, then have my method reset(self) reset the self.text, but i dont know how to make it so they can both stay as self.text because i need to check for whether or not its a empty string or not later on.

i'm new to this any help is very much appreciated

```
class WordSlice:
    
    def __init__(self, text: str):
        self.text = text

    def use(self):
        self.text = ''
        return self.text
    
    def reset(self):
        self.text.replace('', self.text)
        return self.text # i see this is the issue but idk how to fix it
```

Comment: `replace()` doesn't modify the string in place, it returns a new string. You have to assign it back to the variable.

Comment: It's not clear what you intend with that `replace()` call. The string to replace is empty, so it won't modify anything.

Comment: What do you want `reset()` to reset it to? If you want to reset it to its original value, save that in another instance variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as I understand you want to restore the text so it should be stored all the time. But you can control access to the text with a boolean flag. If it is not restored (if set to `False`), the code which uses your class will only be able to get the empty string. Otherwise it will get the actual text.

```
class WordSlice:
    
    def __init__(self, text: str):
        self.__text = text
        self.restored = True

    @property                  # <-- this will allow you to have a function which
    def text():                #     is called as a property, without brackets
        if not self.restored:
            return ''
        return self.__text

    def use(self):
        self.restored = False
        return ''
    
    def reset(self):
        self.restored = True
        return self.__text
```

Extra notes:

1. Strings are immutable. you cannot change them. You can reassign the variable with a new string.
2. `s.replace(x, y)` will not mutate your string. It will return a new string with every occurrence of substring `x` in `s` replaced with string `y`.
3. `self.text = self.text.replace(x, y)` is the code you should use if you want to actually update the value.
4. `s.replace('', x)` will return `x` if `s` is empty, otherwise will return `s`
5. When you say:

```
x = "abc"
x = ''
```

The string `"abc"` will "dissapear" i.e. will not be accessable in your program and will eventually be cleared from memory by garbage collector.

I hope that helps